# How can I ensure that the actions in my RL algorithm are not all over the place?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

**TLDR**: My actions represent a torque of a physical system. How can I make sure that there aren't any large "jumps" between consecutive actions $a_t\rightarrow a_{t+1}$?

---

So I have this very simple simulation of a wing that is connected to a motor. when the motor applies some torque $\tau_{motor}$, the wing rotates with angle $\phi$. My simulation finds $\phi(t)$ in every time window given the ODE $I\ddot\phi = \tau_{motor}-\tau_{drag}$, where $I$ is the wing's moment of inertia and $\tau_{drag}$ is proportional to $(\dot\phi)^2$.

The interesting part is that I treat $\tau_{motor}$ as an action that is given via an RL algorithm - in every timestep I use *PPO* to tell me which action $\tau_{motor}$ is optimal given the state $\phi_t$, and given a reward that is essentially the lift force that the wing generated using that specific action and given that specific state.

As the actions are torques, which is a physical unit - I would like to incorporate some smoothness to them. For example, $a_t=-0.1$ followed by a $a_{t+1}=+0.1$ is not physically possible, as this means the fast transition from negative to positive torque, which is not realizable in real-world problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not simply add $\lambda\sum_{t=1}^T(a_t-a_{t+1})^2$ to your objective function, where $\lambda$ is a positive number?

Comment: I didn't mention it but I am currently working with stable-baseline3, pretty much treating the model as a black-box. are you familiar with adding such regularization to those models?

Comment: oh if you don't have access to the neural net's cost function you could try adding that same term with negative $\lambda$ to the reward; that might be a little tougher to get working though (since the nnet can't see the gradient of that term)

Comment: I'll try, thanks. by the way - I would like to access in the near future to the cost function, do you think its possible given the fact that stable-baseline3 is a pretty simplified wrapper?

Comment: I'm not familiarwith this software, but looking at the source of ppo2.py, it doesn't seem like the variable storing loss is made public (see line188 of https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/blob/master/stable_baselines/ppo2/ppo2.py)